# Should references to DAO be set on every client machine?

Tags: ms-access, reference, dao, frontend

I have Access DB with the front-ends on client machines and back-end on server.

I never needed to use references to DAO, but this time I will have to use it for ConcatRelated module to work. I will have to deploy updated front-ends, but I'm not sure if the reference that I set on my machine will work on other machines.

I don't have any experience with that and I don't know if references will have to be set on each machine (many of them use different versions of Access: 2003, 2007, 2010) or it will get info straight from the front-end.

If it will have to be set everywhere, most likely I will have to find another solution without DAO.

Thank you!

Comment: When you deploy your font-end, it will have the reference set, the problem will arise if the user does not have the library. For most libraries, you can use late binding, but DAO is native to Access, so if the user has Access, they will have a DAO library. Ideally, you should develop in the lowest version of MS Access, because you will have upward compatibility.

Comment: It happened that I use Access 2003 DB version, because I use user rights feature and the library is Microsoft DAO 3.6 Object Library which in my understanding is very old, so it looks that everything should be OK :) Thank you very much for the help!

Comment: Worst case scenario, they can download the Jet DAO library for free, so you should be okay, as long as no one is using Access 64 bit.

Comment: We use only 32-bit MS Office, so it's clear then. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I work in an environment where some users on XP and some are on Win7.  Some use Access 2003 some use Access 2010.   When deploying my databases, broken references is a common problem.

My workaround is to declare my objects using CreateObject instead of via the references.

The following example is what you would use when you have ADO in your references.

```
Dim rst as new ADODB.Recordset
```

The following example is how you can use the ADO Recordset without a reference:

```
Dim rst as Object
Set rst = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
```

This lets the operating system determine the correct library.  Your code completion won't work with this method - so it may be easier to write your code, test it, and then do the CreateObject trick.